# The type "CaliburnApplication" is abstract and must include an explicit value

Tags: caliburn.micro, app.xaml

I'm using Caliburn.Micro 2 beta2 with the new Universal App template.  I'm getting an error with the description "The type "CaliburnApplication" is abstract and must include an explicit value".  My App.xml looks like this:

```
<cm:CaliburnApplication
    x:Class="xxxx.Mobile.Windows.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cm="using:Caliburn.Micro">

</cm:CaliburnApplication>
```

I don't see any problems in the App.xml but I don't know where the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by creating and/or compiling the project on a network share.  I tried deploying/running the Windows Store App head project and it complained about the project originating from a network share, so I moved it to a local drive.  This resolved the error.